# Ansible couldn't resolve module/action 'mssql_script'?

Tags: sql-server, ansible

I'm running an ansible role which updates DB tables according to the DB type (using SQL queries).
As for DB type MSSQL I'm trying to use the
`community.general.mssql_script` module, but can't seem to find it and getting the following error message when running the playbook:

> ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'mssql_script'. This often
> indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

I've tried modifying the script to use the `community.general.mssql_db` module, instead, just to test that the `community.general`'s modules exist and are installed.

Also I've installed the python dependency for the module `pip install pymssql` as stated in the [module documentation page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/mssql_script_module.html).

Additionally, I've tried reinstalling `ansible-galaxy collection install community.general` and, this still did not work.

Is there any other way to explicitly install the `community.general.mssql_script` module or **some other module** which will be used to run the update queries?

Comment: I believe the pip module isn't installed on remote host, try this on on remote: ```pip install pymssql ```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I've tried it and still did not work.

Comment: On which Ansible version are you? `ansible --version`

Comment: I'm running v2.9.6

Comment: And what is your version of the said raised collection? Please provide the result of `ansible-galaxy collection list` in an [edit] of your question.

Comment: I've tried installing v5.8.0 instead and now community.general is v4.8.1 . Trying to fix it with the new version. Is there a way to check if this module exists with the new version?

Comment: 4.8.1 should have it: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/4.8.1/plugins/modules/database/mssql

Comment: From what I can see it was added in [4.0.0](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/4.0.0/plugins/modules/database/mssql) but was not present in [3.8.7](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/3.8.7/plugins/modules/database/mssql)

Comment: That's really helpful, seems like I should have it then in the new version :) I'll give it a go

Comment: All this said, you on an [old unmaintained version of Ansible](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine) and should consider upgrading it too.

Comment: I'm not really sure but the python dependency has to be in the host who run the task. Requires the pymssql Python package on the remote host.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying this in any ansible installed server, try deleting the /home//.ansible/*, after taking a backup. It worked for me.